# After the login is successful, the game information is displayed on the top of the app

Tags: java, android, account, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-account

[image]

After the HUAWEI Account Kit is integrated, a game message is displayed at the top of the app. How can I disable this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to **disable** the Game Service on the [AppGallery Connect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/service/josp/agc/index.html) and this prompt will disappear.

[image]